# Where can I find the Windows GUI Standard?

Tags: windows, user-interface

I've heard they have standard GUI guideline, but I can't seem to find a working link.
Thanks.

Comment: Voting to re-open.  The user is not asking for a recommendation (which is thus subject to opinions) but for a specific resource.  Thus it seems highly unlikely that this would lead to opinionated answers or spam.  In fact this was answered objectively.  Having the question closed could prevent people from keeping the links up to date.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is it the [Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511258.aspx) that you are looking for? Or perhaps rather the [Windows User Experience Guidelines](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=b996e1e7-a83a-4cae-936b-2a9d94b11bc5&displaylang=en) document (~3 MB pdf file)?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for, and the PDF turned out really convenient. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Possibly [Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511258.aspx).