# Is there anything called GUI standards?

Tags: user-interface

GUIs are one of the important areas in most of the software products. I would like to know whether there is something called GUI Standards that defines the best practices in GUI design, but in depth. As an example are there any definitions that contain the best size for a text box or the ratio between the width and hight of a Windows form. (Just to provide maximum ease to the user + best appearance)

While searching I found several articles: [GUI Standards](http://www.enr.state.nc.us/its/pdf/GUIStandards/interact.pdf)

But they seem to be some "Local" standards defined by some organization only for themselves. Do we have something more common/published than this?

I know there is [a standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044008/where-can-i-find-the-windows-gui-standard) from Microsoft as well.. ***But it is just what they do. Not a practices list for best appearance\usability\user experience.***

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look for platform-specific user interface design guides. [Microsoft has one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511258.aspx), as does [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/ue/) and even [GNOME](http://developer.gnome.org/projects/gup/hig/1.0/).

Things like this are quite "cultural", i.e. they change when you move between different operating systems and so on.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is any GUI standard, but for sure there are some good GUI practices.

This article seems helpful

[Principles of Good GUI Design](http://www.classicsys.com/css06/cfm/article.cfm?articleid=20)

I found a similar SO question also

[Best Practices & Principles for GUI design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90813/best-practices-principles-for-gui-design)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [User Experience Patterns (UX Patterns)](http://quince.infragistics.com/#/Main), by Infragistics. It's a nice source of inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest this post : [Best Practices & Principles for GUI design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90813/best-practices-principles-for-gui-design)

Also, in google search, use "usability".

I also read a good book about it. But sorry, it is in French :-(

Answer (score 2):

Use your users as a standard. What works best for them is what is best, so talk to them, show them prototypes and use their feedback as input to the final product.
Have a look at [Jakob Nielsen's Website](http://www.useit.com) for a wealth of usability material.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you're doing. Nearly every platform has their own official and usually a few unofficial ones.

> That's the beauty of standards if you
>   don't like it pick another one

. However GUI is not easy to standardise as there are multiple IO mechanisms - visual, non visual, one way, interactive etc.

No one standard could fit all - except perhaps and ISO or another standards body  and that as we know will be obsolete before it's even completed a first draft.

On the other hand there are various psychologically based user experience techniques that are slowly becoming *de rigeur* standards.

Answer (score 1):

Both Microsoft and Apple have had GUI standards for more than 20 years.

For instance expressed in the books "The Windows Interface. An Application Design Guide" (1987, ISBN 1-55615-439-9) and "Human Interface Guidelines: The Apple Desktop Interface" (1987, ISBN 0-201-17753-6). This information is also online.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines might be what you're looking for...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511258.aspx

Answer (score 0):

windows is originaly based on CUA

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Common_User_Access

although microsoft has gone bananas since Vista, one example is the exchanged order of Edit and View menu commands in the calculator.