# How does design in an operating system work?

Tags: user-interface, coding-style, operating-system

Recently I've been interested in the mechanics of an operating system. In the way that I style HTML pages with CSS, I was wondering what developers use to style an OS so that I can learn more about it. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(1)** Graphical User Interface (GUI) (see also [Wikipedia: Graphical user interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface)) for different OS platforms is typically composed of widgets provided by OS-specific GUI toolkits (see also [Wikipedia: List of widget toolkits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits))

The way how developers "style" the user interface depends on what the toolkit enables and on what the platform dictates (see also [Stack Overflow: Is there anything called GUI standards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388300/is-there-anything-called-gui-standards))

---

**(2)** For example, in order to learn the way how to create and "style" an application that will run on the Windows desktop OS you can start at [Windows → Dev Center - Desktop → Getting Started Developing User Interfaces for Windows Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff728822(v=vs.85).aspx) where the section called "[Implementing a User Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff728823(v=vs.85).aspx)" will throw you quite directly towards the GUI API provided by the OS.

You can find one another very concrete example related to the `Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)` widget library (just one of the possible choices) in article [Microsoft Developer Network → Windows Presentation Foundation → Styling and Templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683(v=vs.110).aspx)

Different Operating Systems use different native widget libraries and different sets of APIs and different `User Interface Design Guidelines`. You can use the links in part **(1)** to find them